# Scrollbar in android

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

How I can add scrollbar in android xml file???
Can anyone prtovide me the simple way to add it in relative layout.
I tried many times to add it in relative and linear layout.
But,It doesn't work.
Please give me solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference to above answer:

HOW TO USE RELATIVE LAYOUT W.R.T. SCROLLVIEW

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >


    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >         
    ... ... ...

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your relative or linear layout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). For example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- contents of linear layout go here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```